# What is the name of a table that joins two other tables?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity

What is the name for a database entity that joins two other entities using composite keys? I'm asking as I need to write a theoretical definition for such tables but could not find any definition online.

Comment: [Junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)

Answer (score 2):

That's associative entity. I think that comes from ordinary object orientation where an association is a relationship between two different objects, like a driver and a car.

See more at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity